# Asertos en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el sigiente código el cual la función deberá devolver el factorial del número pasado como parámetro.

La función deberá usar asertos para comprobar que el valor pasado sea un número entero positivo. En caso de no serlo, la función terminará con una excepción AssertionError con el mensaje "He usado asertos para mostrar esta excepción"

```
def fact(number):
    cont = 1
    assert number >= 0
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        cont *= i
    return cont
    assert number < 0, "He usado asertos para mostrar esta excepción"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(fact(5))
```

El problema es que para los casos en que los inputs son positivos el programa devuelve correctamente el resultado factorial, pero para los casos en los que los inputs son negativos no devuelve el correspondiente mensaje propio del "assert". También probé de la siguiente manera pero se sigue produciendo el mismo error

```
def fact(number):
        cont = 1
        assert number >= 0
        for i in range(1, number + 1):
            cont *= i
        return cont
        assert number < 0
        raise AssertionError("He usado asertos para mostrar esta excepción")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print(fact(5))
```

Comment: Has puesto un `assert` después del `return`, por lo que no será ejecutado nunca. Date cuenta de que el assert es una instrucción más y sólo se ejecutará si el flujo de ejecución pasa por ella. Por otro lado, la excepción y el mensaje se generan sólo si el aserto no se cumple, así que el mensaje debería ir en el primer aserto que verifica que sea positivo. El segundo aserto sobra.

Comment: No, no es una estructura de control. Explicarlo bien no me cabe en el comentario, de modo que te he escrito una respuesta. De paso indico que el uso de aserciones para verificar parámetros no es lo más apropiado y doy otra alternativa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un assert no es una estructura de control, sino una sentencia que no tiene relación con las que le preceden ni las que le siguen. Tienen esta forma general:

```
assert expresion_booleana_que_debe_ser_cierta, "Mensaje si es falsa"
```

Simplemente se verifica que la expresión booleana sea cierta. Si es falsa se genera la excepción `AssertionError` con el mensaje indicado entre comillas.

Las aserciones son salvaguardas contra casos que *no deberían ocurrir nunca*. Es decir, el programador sabe que, llegados a ese punto del código y si no hay bugs, la expresión booleana *será cierta siempre* y por tanto la excepción nunca se genera. Digamos que la aserción se pone "por si acaso" (por si realmente el programa tenía un bug y resulta que la condición es falsa, para que en ese caso el programa rompa inmediatamente debido a la excepción en lugar de continuar con un valor erróneo).

Por tanto tu función debería ser así:

```
def fact(number):
    # El número ha de ser positivo, en caso contrario abortar
    assert number >= 0, "El numero debe ser positivo pero se ha recibido {}".format(number)

    # Si llegamos aqui, es que el número era positivo
    cont = 1
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        cont *= i
    return cont
```

En todo caso, es mala práctica usar aserciones para cosas como las de este ejemplo.  Aquí estamos verificando que un parámetro recibido por una función está en el rango previsto, pero si no es así no es algo achacable a un bug que hayas cometido. Más bien la culpa es de quien llamó a la función que le pasó un valor no permitido. Lo lógico en este caso es, en lugar de usar aserciones, usar un condicional para verificar el dato, y si no es correcto generar una excepción `ValueError`. Así es como se comportan las funciones de la biblioteca Python cuando reciben un valor inválido.

Sería por tanto:

```
def fact(number):
    if number < 0:
        raise ValueError(
               "El numero debe ser positivo pero se ha recibido {}".format(number)
              )

    # Si llegamos aqui, es que el número era positivo
    cont = 1
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        cont *= i
    return cont
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda. He podido entender uso del assert claramente

Answer (score 1):

Como bien se menciona en los comentarios el `assert` colocado luego del `return` nunca llega a ser ejecutado:

El código utilizando `assert` debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
def fact(number):
    assert number >= 0, "He usado asertos para mostrar esta excepción"
    cont = 1
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        cont *= i
    return cont


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(fact(5))
```

El equivalente utilizando `AssertionError` quedaría de esta manera:

```
def fact(number):
    if number < 0:
        raise AssertionError("He usado asertos para mostrar esta excepción")
    cont = 1
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        cont *= i
    return cont


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(fact(5))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda